# Mosquito server send last will message even the clients are still connected and sending messages

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am using mosquitto server (version 1.5.7). I am using this older version because this is most compatible with the IoT  device I am working with.

As subscription client, I am using eclipse paho library (python version).

I set the keepAlive interval to 60 (which is also the default).

But the problem is, the server sending last will message even under a second (whereas IoT device is still alive).

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely (based on the limited information in the question) you have set the LWT message to be published as a retained message, so until you publish something new (or publish a retained message with a null payload) this message will ALWAYS be delivered to a new client when they subscribe to that topic.